# Days should be added based on the integer values

Tags: c#

in thevariable `int days` I will get the integer value.

another variable eg  Totalhours :"40:00"

```
if (oddt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int days = Convert.ToInt32(oddt.Rows["fltOD"]);
}
```

for eg:if value returns as 1 means it should add 8 hours in this total hours string  and display as Totalhours : "48:00"
if the values returns as 2 means it should add 16 hours in this taotal hours string and display as totalhours :"56:00" 
if the values returns as 0.5 means it should add 4 hours in this taotal hours string and display as totalhours :"44:00"
like this dynamically based on the value returns in this int days it should be added.

Comment: Wow, i quess i know what your asking but please fix your question! if the value returns as 0.5 it should add 16 hours?? you mean 4 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(40d + 8d * days);
string timeString = Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours) + ":" + (ts.Minutes < 10 ? "0" + ts.Minutes : ts.Minutes.ToString());
```

Comment: This doesnt work since his days property might be a floating point value  like 0.5, or worse, 0.4. You have to catch the rest and add it as minutes

Comment: @Polity: +1 Good point, I've edited. For non-integer days, the `days` variable will need to be declared as a `double`.

Comment: No overload for method 'FromHours' takes '3' arguments i am getting error

Comment: I'm having an off day aren't I!! Try again.

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: Oh right, it's a .NET 4 feature. I'll edit.

Comment: 2.00:00:00 output like this it is coming.....i need 40:00:00 it should sas 48:00:00

Comment: Check my edit. If it still doesn't work, put a breakpoint and check the value for `days` is being calculated correctly.

Comment: thanks it is coming likes this 48:0 it should show as 48:00:00

Comment: Right, millionth time lucky. This is the problem with posting untested code :/

Comment: thanks but in the datatable i will get like this dtblresult.Rows[0]["TotalHRS"] how to do in that code in case of the 40d as satic

Comment: Replace `40d` with `Convert.ToDouble(dtblresult.Rows[0]["TotalHRS"])`

Answer (score 0):

I would first sum up all the hour values and at the end format totalHours into the desired string.

```
        double totalHours;

        foreach (var row in oddt.Rows)
        {
            totalHours += Convert.ToDouble(oddt["fltOD"]) * 8;
        }
```

BTW: An `int` could never hold a value like `0.5` it must be a double!